# Error al Insertar datos!1

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Un saludo amigos, tengo el siguiente inconveniente es un error que no alcanzo a identificar muy bien, este error me aparece al insertar datos en la tabla, ya verifique la conexión y la sentencia pero no detecto el error, como se dan cuenta estoy recibiendo los datos con metodo POST provenientes de un formulario.

Este es el error al enviar los datos desde el formulario:

```
Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\login1\sistema\insert.php on line 10
Error al ingresar los datos
```

Este es el código que realiza el insert, archivo insert.php, este es el archivo que recibe los datos provenientes del formulario de inserción

```
<?php


    NuevoAlumno($_POST['nombres'], $_POST['apellidos'], $_POST['fnacimiento'], $_POST['edadcumplida'], $_POST['grado'], $_POST['dirgrupo'], $_POST['direccion'], $_POST['comuna'], $_POST['telcontacto']);

    function NuevoAlumno($nombres, $apellidos, $fnacimiento, $edadcumplida, $grado, $dirgrupo, $direccion, $comuna, $telcontacto)
    {
        include 'conexion.php';
        $sentencia="INSERT INTO tbl_alumnos (nombres, apellidos, fnacimiento, edadcumplida, grado, dirgrupo, direccion, comuna, telcontacto) VALUES ('".$nombres."', '".$apellidos."', '".$fnacimiento."', '".$edadcumplida."', '".$grado."', '".$dirgrupo."', '".$direccion."', '".$comuna."', '".$telcontacto."')";
        $mbd->query($sentencia) or die ("Error al ingresar los datos".mysqli_error($mbd, $sentencia));


    }

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Alumno Ingresado Éxitosamente");
    alert("Ahora registre información de los acudientes")
    window.location.href='index.php';
</script>
```

Este el código del formulario de donde proviene los datos, frm_registrar.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      function valida(){
    if (document.frm.grado.value == "")
     alert("Seleccione el Grado del Alumno");
    else
     document.frm.submit();
   }  
    </script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>IE | Industrial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section id="container">

            <form action="insert.php" method="post" name="frm">

            <h2>Ingresar Alumno</h2>
            <img src="images/agregar.fw.png" alt="Login">
            <input type="text" REQUIRED name="nombres" placeholder="Nombres">
            <input type="text" REQUIRED name="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos">
            <input type="date" REQUIRED name="fnacimiento" placeholder="Fecha de Nacimiento">
            <input type="text" REQUIRED name="edadcumplida" placeholder="Edad">

            <select name="grado" id="grados">
        <option selected="selected" disabled="" REQUIRED>Grado</option>

        <?php
          include_once 'conexion.php';
          $sql= 'SELECT * FROM tbl_grado';
          $sentencia = $mbd->prepare($sql);
          $sentencia->execute();
          $resultado = $sentencia->fetchAll();
        ?>

        <?php 
        foreach($resultado as $grados):
        ?>

           <option value="<?php echo $grados['grado'] ?>"><?php echo $grados['grado'] ?></option>
        <?php
    endforeach
        ?>
            </select>


            <select name="comuna" id="comuna">
        <option selected="selected" disabled="" REQUIRED>Comuna</option>

    <?php
          include_once 'conexion.php';
          $sql= 'SELECT * FROM tbl_comunas';
          $sentencia = $mbd->prepare($sql);
          $sentencia->execute();
          $resultado = $sentencia->fetchAll();
        ?>

        <?php 
        foreach($resultado as $comunas):
        ?>

           <option value="<?php echo $comunas['comuna'] ?>"><?php echo $comunas['comuna'] ?></option>
        <?php
    endforeach
        ?>
            </select>

            <select name="dirgrupo" id="directores">
        <option selected="selected" disabled="" REQUIRED>Director Grupo</option>
                <?php
                include_once 'conexion.php';
                $sql= 'SELECT * FROM tbl_dirgrupo';
                $sentencia = $mbd->prepare($sql);
                $sentencia->execute();
                $resultado = $sentencia->fetchAll();
        ?>

        <?php 
        foreach($resultado as $directores):
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $directores['nombres_dir'] ?>"><?php echo $directores['nombres_dir'] ?></option>
        <?php
    endforeach
        ?>
        </select>
            <input type="text" REQUIRED name="direccion" placeholder="Direcciòn">
            <input type="text" REQUIRED name="telcontacto" placeholder="Telefono">
            <input type="submit" value="INGRESAR" onclick="valida()">

    </form>
  </body>
</html>


Esta es la estructura de la tabla alumnos tbl_alumnos:

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQS2P.png

---

Esta es la estructura de la tabla tbl_alumnos:

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8JBi.png
```

Comment: No necesitas pasar la variable `$sentencia` a `mysqli_error`

Comment: Lo he corregido justo ahí, solo dejando la variable $mbd que es la conexión, pero el error continua en la misma linea.

Comment: podrias colocar la estructura de tu tabla `tbl_alumnos`

Comment: Es el mismo error u otro diferente?

Comment: Puedes agregar conexion.php para ver el codigo de la conexion

Comment: Ok te la añado a la pegunta.

Comment: Este es el código de la conexión.php: 
<?php
try {
    $mbd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ieindustrial', 'root', '');
  //echo 'conectado';
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que noto te hace falta insertar una columna que seria la del `id_alumno` y por lo que veo lo tienes en **auto_incremente** por lo tanto supongo que es la razon por la que no lo pusiste..

Por lo tanto puedes colocar `NULL` en la parte donde deberia ir el `id_alumno`

entonces agrega `id_alumno` donde especificas las columnas a insertar y en `VALUES` agrega `NULL`
podrías intentar colocar tu inserción de la siguiente manera.

```
$sentencia="INSERT INTO tbl_alumnos (id_alumno,nombres, apellidos, fnacimiento, edadcumplida, grado, dirgrupo, direccion, comuna, telcontacto) VALUES (NULL, '".$nombres."', '".$apellidos."', '".$fnacimiento."', '".$edadcumplida."', '".$grado."', '".$dirgrupo."', '".$direccion."', '".$comuna."', '".$telcontacto."')";
```

otra manera de hacerlo es quitando las columnas que se insertaran ya que se esta insertando en todas las columnas

de la siguiente manera

```
$sentencia=" INSERT INTO tbl_alumnos VALUES (NULL, '".$nombres."', '".$apellidos."', '".$fnacimiento."', '".$edadcumplida."', '".$grado."', '".$dirgrupo."', '".$direccion."', '".$comuna."', '".$telcontacto."')";
```

Comment: Gracias he realizado los cambio y ahora sale este Warning: Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\login1\sistema\insert.php on line 10
Error al ingresar los datos

Comment: si el id es PK y AUTO INCREMENT, entonces no hace falta ni invocar el nombre de la columna y menos pasarle un valor, pues el gestor lo hará por nosotros

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta intenta agregando `id_alumno` donde se especifica la columna a insertar me dices si resulta

Comment: @Aprendiz supongo que si, aun que en algunos casos da error por no considerar el campo de la PK por lo tanto para evitar error en mi caso he colocado `NULL` ya que de lo contrario me da error. en caso de no ser ese el error tendria que revisarse con mas detalle del por que el error.

Comment: El error continua incluso colocando en la consulta NULL como parametro

Comment: @Sergio creo que tu error es que estas usando **PDO** y para ver el error usas **mysqli**  por lo tanto pide un parametro de tipo mysql intenta quitar esa parte ya que no he trabajado con **PDO** no sabria como sustituir esa linea, intenta que quede de la siguiente manera `$mbd->query($sentencia);`

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias por sus aportes valiosos.